# Maven: exclude resource from child module

Tags: java, maven, jar

How to remove a resource from child module?

Scenario:

In common.jar we have xml files that we want to exclude. But common jar is added as dependency in module1.jar and module2.jar. module1 and module2 have test cases that uses xml files in common jar.

So, I want to exclude xml files after the test cases has run.

So, is there a way to remove xml from child modules in parent pom. Or any other approach to remove xml from common jar.

Parent pom.xml:

```xml
<modules>
    <module>common</module>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove goal of [truezip-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/) does the task of removing xml file from the jar in the final pom.xml file.

Answer (score 2):

You can exclude resources from being packaged into the resulting `jar` using the [`excludes`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html) attribute of the [`maven-resources-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/).

For example, to exclude the file `src/main/resources/path/to/file.xml`, you could have the following inside the POM of `common`:

```xml
<build>
  ...
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>path/to/file.xml</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
    ...
  </resources>
  ...
</build>
```

---

However, if you want to modify the `common` artefact after it was built, this will not be possible: by the time Maven is building `module1` and `module2`, it will have already packaged and installed `common`.

In that case, you should move the corresponding XML files inside `module1` and `module2` as a test resource, i.e. inside `src/test/resources`. By adding these XML files as test resources, you ensure they are present in the classpath when the tests are running and that they will not be packaged in the final jar.

Comment: Test cases of module1 and module 2 will fail in this approach as they refer file.xml in common jar

Comment: @VikasSharma In your question, you say you want to "remove xml from common jar.". Did I misunderstand?

Comment: yes, I want to remove xml from common jar. But, by removing it from common jar, the test cases written in module1 will fail because they need the xml file. So, I nee a solution that will remove from common jar after running all the test cases in module1 and module2.

Comment: @VikasSharma That is not possible. Maven will have already built and installed common jar by the time it is building module1 and module2 so you can't update it. Why not move the xml file inside module1 and module2 and make it a test resources?

Comment: Move the xml file to 'src/test/resources'  and it will not being packaged but is available in the tests.

Comment: yes Tunaki, if nothing works then I have to do that.

Comment: khmarbaise, do you mean to move xml file from src/amin/resources to src/test/resources. Or, to use a plugin in pom.xml to move it to scr/test/resources

Comment: Is there any plugin that can do it? Or I have to write my own plugin

Comment: @VikasSharma You mean to move the files? Just do it by hand. Or are those files generated?